# How can I implement virtual try-on for shirts using Flutter AR?

Tags: flutter, mobile, augmented-reality

Flutter AR Try-On Shirt

I am working on a final year project in flutter which is based on **AR**. My project is smart wear app in flutter which will virtually try-on shirt on user.

I am stuck in my project because I can't find any good source or library to implement AR (virtually try-on shirt) functionality in Flutter.

I tried different resources like deepar.ai and search a lot but didn't find any good resource.

Answer (score 0):

As per I know, no ready-made SDK/plugin is available in the market. You need to depend on native code. for that, you may follow ARCore on Android and ARKit on iOS

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a plugin for Augmented Reality in flutter please check this out `ar_flutter_plugin: ^0.7.3`